# Identify differences between HBA SR and 10GB SR card by visual inspection

Tags: hp, 10gbethernet, hba

I would know if exists visual differences between "8Gb FC SR HBA" and "10GbE-SR 2p PCIe Adapter" cards in order to identify them watching the cards installed in the server rear without access to the bios, management console or other software.
In my case I'm interested in identify HBA and 10Ethernet of HP Server (Integrity and Proliant) .

Answer (score 2):

As these are both HP products, you should be able to find a sticker on each with a part number (probably labled p/n) that you can look up on the HP website to identify which is which.